Incompatible shapes Error while using my model in a C# app
I am having problems with an image classificator model developed in python that I want to use in a C# industrial application.
This is the model structure:
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(len(class_names), activation='softmax')
])

This is the code I use in C#:
var modelfile = "D:\\Soft\\Soft\\C#\\LastVersion\\frozen_model.pb";
var labels = new[] { "ORANGE", "BANANA", "APPLE", "MIX" };

var graph = new Graph().as_default();
graph.Import(File.ReadAllBytes(modelfile));

using (var session = tf.Session(graph))
{
    var tensor = ImageToTensor(RutaImagen);

    var input_op = graph.OperationByName("sequential_1/conv2d_1/convolution");  
    var output_op = graph.OperationByName("sequential_1/dense_1_2/Softmax");  

    // this next line gives me a Runtime Error
    var result = session.run(output_op.outputs[0], (input_op.outputs[0], tensor));


    var results = result.ToArray<float>();
    float totalConfidence = results.Sum();

    int[] quantized = Quantized(results);

    label1.Text = "Resultados cuantizados:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        label1.Text += $"{labels[i]}:\n" +
                       $"  Valor original: {results[i]:0.000}\n" +
                       $"  Probabilidad: {results[i] * 100:0.00}%\n" +
                       $"  Normalizado: {(results[i] / totalConfidence) * 100:0.00}%\n" +
                       $"  Cuantizado: {(results[i] >= 0.5 ? "Probable" : "No probable")}\n";
    }

The code of ImageToTensor function I call to preprocess the image:
        private static NDArray ImageToTensor(string file)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file);
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap, new Size(imgWidth, imgHeight));

            // Convertir la imagen a un tensor
            float[,,,] input = new float[1, imgHeight, imgWidth, 3];
            for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++)
                {
                    Color pixel = resizedBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                    input[0, y, x, 0] = pixel.R / 255.0f;
                    input[0, y, x, 1] = pixel.G / 255.0f;
                    input[0, y, x, 2] = pixel.B / 255.0f;
                }
            }
            //return new DenseTensor<float>(input);
            return np.array(input);
        }

And finally the Runtime Error:
While executing
var result = session.run(output_op.outputs[0], (input_op.outputs[0], tensor));
Tensorflow.InvalidArgumentError
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Incompatible shapes: [1,1,1,32] vs. [1,200,150,3]
     [[{{node sequential_1/conv2d_1/add}}]]
  Source=Tensorflow.Binding
  StackTrace:
   at Tensorflow.Status.Check(Boolean throwException)
   at Tensorflow.BaseSession._call_tf_sessionrun(KeyValuePair`2[] feed_dict, TF_Output[] fetch_list, List`1 target_list)
   at Tensorflow.BaseSession._do_run(List`1 target_list, List`1 fetch_list, Dictionary`2 feed_dict)
   at Tensorflow.BaseSession._run(Object fetches, FeedItem[] feed_dict)
   at Tensorflow.BaseSession.run(Tensor fetche, FeedItem[] feed_dict)
   at Test2.Form1.EvaluarImagen(String RutaImagen) in D:\Soft\Soft\C#\LastVersion\Test2\Form1.cs:line 103
   at Test2.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Soft\Soft\C#\LastVersion\Test2\Form1.cs:line 26
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(HWND hWnd, MessageId msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)


Can someone give me a hand? Im desperate
Thank you all

Hello.
It seems solved by replacing this:
var input_op = graph.OperationByName("sequential_1/conv2d_1/convolution");
for this:
var input_op = graph.OperationByName("x");
